# Include additional field in inlineformset_factory where dealing with an ImageField

Tags: django, inline-formset

Using Django I'm creating a thumbnail of an image uploaded using a standard ImageField, adding the path  to a table in a separate field 'thumbnail' alongside the usual imagefile field. I'm trying to work out how to access the thumbnail path where rendering the imagefield objects in a custom template using a formset so that I can display it.

I guess I need to add a 'form=CarImageForm' to inlineformset_factory and then modify my forms.py but I'm having trouble working out how to do it or even whether this approach is the right one. For clarity I have not included my attempts to do so in the code samples below.

My end goal is to return the thumbnail image which links to the original image - already displayed via the Imagefile field.

Thanks in advance!

template is:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label }}: {{ field }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Enter"/></p>
```

forms.py:

```
class CarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        exclude = ['owner', 'uploaded']
```

views.py:

```
# Edit an existing record
@login_required
def edit_existing(request, object_id=False):
    try:
        car = Car.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    except Car.DoesNotExist:    
        raise Http404   
    ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Car, CarImage, extra=1, max_num=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CarForm(request.POST, instance=car)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=car)
        if formset.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            # Handle form.save() to include user id
            new_car = form.save(commit=False)
            new_car.owner = request.user
            new_car.save()
            # Formset - contains the attached images
            formset.save()  
            return HttpResponseRedirect(new_car.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = forms.CarForm(instance=car)
        formset = ImageFormSet(instance=car)
    return render_to_response('edit_existing.html',
        {'form': form, 'formset': formset},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
    uploaded = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today,editable=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('vehicle_admin.views.car_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

def orig_car_id_folder(instance, filename):
    return 'uploads/images/orig/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.car_id, filename)

def thumb_car_id_folder(instance, filename):
    return 'uploads/images/thumb/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.car_id, filename)

class CarImage(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    imagefile = models.ImageField(upload_to=orig_car_id_folder)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=thumb_car_id_folder, editable=False)

    # PIL tips from 
    # https://snipt.net/danfreak/generate-thumbnails-in-django-with-pil/
    # http://www.mechanicalgirl.com/post/image-resizing-file-uploads-doing-it-easy-way/
    def save(self):
        import os
        from PIL import Image
        from cStringIO import StringIO
        from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
        THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (75, 75)
        super(CarImage, self).save() # Use the commit=False param here?
        image = Image.open(self.imagefile.path)
        if image.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
            image = image.convert('RGB')
        image.thumbnail(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        temp_handle = StringIO()
        image.save(temp_handle, 'png')
        temp_handle.seek(0)
        name_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(self.imagefile.name)[-1])
        suf = SimpleUploadedFile(name_ext[0],
                temp_handle.read(), content_type='image/png')
        self.thumbnail.save(suf.name+'.png', suf, save=False)
        super(CarImage, self).save()
```

Comment: My problem was setting editable=False in my model for the 'thumbnail' field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a basic oversight on my part.

My problem was setting editable=False in my CarImage model for the 'thumbnail' field. This is fine for the initial data submission but causes problems where editing the entry as that field is automatically excluded in the form. (See my code snippets above for more info.)

My next step would be to set up a custom Form for my add_new view (I did not initially include this view but it is what I was using to enable the initial upload of data) like this:

```
class InitialCarImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CarImage
        exclude = ['thumbnail']
```

I guess that the right approach is to use editable=False but unless I'm committing a grave mistake taking this approach it will probably work for me.

I'm new to the site so please let me know if answering my question in this way is the correct way to close it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to try using my [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) library, you could do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from extra_views import UpdateWithInlinesView, InlineFormSet


class CarForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = self.kwargs.pop('user')
        super(CarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True)
        instance = super(CarForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.user

        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        exclude = ['owner', 'uploaded']


CarImageInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = CarImage
    extra = 1
    max_num = 1


UpdateCarView(UpdateWithInlinesView):
    pk_url_kwarg = 'object_id'
    inlines = [CarImageInline]
    template_name = 'edit_existing.html'
    form_class = CarForm

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UpdateCarView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UpdateCarView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()
```

Key differences:

- The form becomes responsible for assigning the user to the car, the form gets hold of the user when it's instantiated (see get_form_kwargs). The reason to do it this way is that with class-based views, overriding the form_valid (or in this case forms_valid) is a little clunky, so I prefer putting stuff in the form.
- Instead of getting `formset` in your context, you get `inlines`, which is a list of formsets. This is because you could technically have as many inline formsets as you want, even though in this case you only have one, it's effectively the same as how the Django admin works.
- Overriding `dispatch` to apply the `login_required` decorator is clunky, fortunately it's something that's easily abstracted into a mixin, see [django-braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces) for some ready-made ones.

Comment: I had noticed your code when searching around for answers to handling inline forms but thought as a noob I would try to work around it without using any additional libraries - so your comments are a welcome addition as to why I should consider using it. I also appreciate your comments regarding overriding dispatch with login_required decorator and the use of mixins as an improved way to achieve it. This is some useful insight into Django with two useful libraries to check out. Thanks for your reply and apologies for not replying sooner.